# Do something different depending on what the user clicks on

Tags: javascript, html

I have three anchor links:

```
<a name="send1" href="#signup" >go 1</a>
<a name="send2" href="#signup" >go 2</a>
<a name="send3" href="#signup" >go 3</a>
```

When the user clicks a link the same pop up form is shown:

```
    <div id="signup"> 
        <form action="send_form.php">                     
            <input name="text" type="text">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

"send_form.php" is executed when the user clicks "Send". I want to check which link was clicked, and do something different.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to RECORD which link the user clicked? Or you want to do something different depending on what the user clicked?

Comment: @TheMonk I want to do something different depending on what user clicked!

Comment: Then it's got absolutely nothing to do with PHP. You'll be wanting Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not know this simply from PHP. This is something you would find out by using javascript (or better yet, jQuery).

The approach would be to:

- trap the click event on all anchor tags
- assign the name (or better yet, ID) to a variable
- add the variable's ID to a hidden field in the form

This is what it would look like using jQuery:

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AkRD2/)

HTML:

```
<a name="send1" id="send1" href="#signup">go 1</a>
<a name="send2" id="send2" href="#signup">go 2</a>
<a name="send3" id="send3" href="#signup">go 3</a>

<div id="signup">
    <form action="send_form.php">
        <input name="text" type="text">
        <input name="hidden_field" id="hidden_field" type="hidden" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var the_anchor;

$('#signup').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    close: function(){
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});

$('a').click(function() {
    the_anchor = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#hidden_field').val(the_anchor);
    $('#signup').dialog('open');
});
```

---

Note that if you are using jQuery, you must reference the jQuery libraries in the `<head>` tags of the document:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't do that using only PHP.

What I mean is that you're trying to understand what link has been pressed, which is nothing that has to do with the form itself.

To accomplish this, I would suggest you to use javascript OR jQuery to set an hidden field inside the form and, then, send it.

Example:

Link:

```
<a href="#test" name="test">link</a>
```

Form:

```
<div id="signup"> 
    <form action="send_form.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="linkPressed" />
        <input name="text" type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

javascript (assuming jQuery):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#linkPressed').val($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

send_form.php:

```
$pressedlinkname = $_POST['linkPressed'];
```

And there you are.

Don't take it as the exact solution of your problem: inspire your solution by following this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The hash (#) portion of a URL is used on the client side only. It will never appear in server logs, requests, or as part of a REFERRER string. You have to send it via FORM (using javascript) eg.:

```
<input name="hash" type="text">
```

and change the value of input using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Javascript!

```
//html
<a name="send1" href="#signup" onclick="myFunction(1)>go 1</a>
<a name="send2" href="#signup" onclick="myFunction(2)>go 2</a>
<a name="send3" href="#signup" onclick="myFunction(3)>go 3</a>

<div id="signup"> 
    <form action="send_form.php">                     
        <input name="text" type="text">               
        <input id="clicked" type="hidden" value=0>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div> 
//js
function myFunction(x){
   document.getElementById("clicked").value = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a hidden input in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="clicked_link" name="clicked_link" value="" />
```

Then use some jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#clicked_link').val($(this).attr('name'));
    });
});
```

Or you could use pure javascript I suppose, but it is similar approach..