# Execute jquery only once

Tags: jquery, dialog

Can anyone help me, I have a script here that displays a dialog when your mouse leaves the page, but I only want it to execute once, after the first time, I dont want it to happen again.
Here my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#dialog {
    width:652px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display:none;
}
</style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>

function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
            // stop your drag event here
            // for now we can just use an alert
            if (count < 1) {
              $(function() {
                var count = 1;
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                width:692
                });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog">
<img src="http://www.maxcashtitleloans.com/POPUPIMAGE.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Change your code to use jQuery for the event handling, and use the `.one()` function to execute the handler only once. Looks like you could also simply declare `count` in the global scope and not inside the event handler.

Comment: I cant figure out the jquery for the mouse event handleing

Comment: Your code does not reference a jQueryUI stylesheet. This is not important to your question, but may be important later (your dialog won't work without it). See the last part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507851/do-something-different-depending-on-what-the-user-clicks-on/20507989#20507989) for an example.

Comment: This code should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/6c5m7/. Also, http://learn.jquery.com is a great resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to have `count = 1;`

instead of `var count = 1;` (~line 47)

and `count = 0;` instead of `var count = 0;` (line 29)

line 29 (`var count = 0;`) defines the variable 'count', but count cannot be overridden or increased in your code as it is not in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Copy/Paste this code and see if ti works for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

        <style>
            #dialog {
                width:652px;
                margin-right:auto;
                margin-left:auto;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var count = 0;

                function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = src;
                    img.width = width;
                    img.height = height;
                    img.alt = alt;

                    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                }
                function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
                    if (obj.addEventListener) {
                        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
                    }
                    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
                        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
                    }
                }
                addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
                    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
                        e = e ? e : window.event;
                        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
                        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
                            // stop your drag event here
                            // for now we can just use an alert
                            if (count < 1) {
                                $(function() {
                                    count = 1;
                                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                                        width:692
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="dialog">
        <img src="http://www.maxcashtitleloans.com/POPUPIMAGE.jpg">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1_Unbind the event doing this (you need to use jquery events for this)

```
$(this).unbind("mouseOut");
```

2_Do it the worse way and use a flag like this

```
var flag=1;
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        if(flag){
            flag=0;
            e = e ? e : window.event;
            var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
            if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
                // stop your drag event here
                // for now we can just use an alert
                if (count < 1) {
                    $(function() {
                        var count = 1;
                        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                            width:692
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```